# One question in 3 review queue

Tags: support, review

I noticed one thing, If a question report in the 3 review categories like this

1. First Posts
2. Late Answers
3. Low Quality Posts

Now I click on the First post and approve it.
I go back that post gone from all 3 categories. fine, i thought other user pick the post.

but that is not case.

to verify this i wait couple of days, i note down the daily reviews in the each category. Once a post showed in 2 or 3 categories then i approve one and go back to check the count.

Only the category which I approved increased by 1, other simply same and item disappear from  que.

Is it Bug or expected behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One post can span all of the categories. This can be seen by a new user, providing a comment like "I'm having this problem too did you find a solution?" to an old post. This would result in it spanning all 3 categories.

The queue in which you approve it will determine what point you get and the act of approving it from one queue clears it from the others.

Comment: Let's say if i approve it from First post's que then it will be cleared out from other 2 as well....But there is possibility that 1st post will be fine but not correct in the low quality or may be in late answer....in this case the above logic is not good.